# Modify first phone number and saved it android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to retrieve the first phone number using the code below, add a zero in front of that number and saved the phone number. I am new to this and up to now and the code below open the contact list, then the user select a phone number and the phone number is displayed as a toast. However, i want the first phone number in my contact list to get a zero in front and then get saved. I know i am not far from the solution but while am trying, it would be faster if i get your help. Thanks.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
       public static final int PICK_CONTACT    = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        // and the intent.setType
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
        Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
}
```